# Christmas tree of variable height and width

Tags: python

I know Christmas is over, but I found a great task on the internet, and I would be very interested in the solution to it. The following Christmas tree should be output via Python:
[image]

Since I unfortunately only know the basics of Python, I would be very interested in a solution. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

I've searched the web for code that prints the tree similarly, but haven't found anything.

Many greetings

Comment: So why is this a python question? This could be done in any language. Do you know any python?

Comment: @quamrana - I'm interested in a solution using Python and no other programming language

Comment: You can achieve that with exactly 18 *print()* statements. You'll find the documentation illuminating:- https://docs.python.org/3/

Comment: It looks like a geometry problem - something about the relationship of the base of a triangle to its height (which is your variable). And you have to make some decision about the "trunk" of the tree. Give it a shot. This will be much more satisfying to do yourself than having someone do it for you (in any case, SO is not a code-writing service).

Comment: This looks like someone's homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the top half of the tree, the number of asterisks on each line is `1 + 2 * line number`. You can use `str.center` to place those asterisks in between dots on the left and right.

```py
def tree(n : int):
    line_len = 1 + 2 * (n - 1)
    for i in range(1, line_len + 1, 2):
        print(("*" * i).center(line_len, "."))
    for i in range(3):
        print(("*" * 3).center(line_len, "."))
tree(15)
```